# get an int value with @Value

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have application.properties file and I successfully get String values from it with @Value. I am having problems getting an int from it.

```
jedisHostName=127.0.0.1
redisPort=6379
```

In my config class I have

```
@Value("${jedisHostName}")
private String hostName;
```

and it works fine, but when I try to

```
@Value("#{new Integer.parseInt('${redisPort}')}")
private Integer redisPort;
```

I get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'secret***': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'redisPort';
```

I am also trying only

```
@Value("#{new Integer('${redisPort}')}")
```

but I get same exception. I am even trying to simply do a

```
@Value("${redisPort}")
private String redisPort;

int jedisPort = Integer.parseInt(redisPort.trim());
```

but then I get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'secret***' defined in file [secret***.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate **** Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have normal class names but I use "secret***" just for the example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply:

```
@Value("${redisPort}")
private Integer redisPort;
```

should work. You should not do any parsing yourself, it will be taken care for you by higher forces.

Comment: I did try but then there is TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'

Comment: Are you sure that the reading of `jedisHostName` works? If it does, I don't see how the other one won't work. One thing you could check is whether you have some strange characters in `redisPort` (besides digits).

Comment: It works 100% because I build the project and everything was running as intended. I forgot to move the port into application.properties though and I did it afterwards and I can't figure way to do it. It is clean redisPort=6379 without spaces or other characters. Not only this but I have 4 String properties that work, but only showed one for shorter example. Whole idea is that those Strings were hard-coded and I needed to move them to application.properties